# ReportViewer corrupt toolbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of the *ReportViewer* object embedded in a `.aspx` page.
After fighting with references I reached a stable configuration that's well depicted from this fragment of `Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" />
          <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

In the .aspx page the ReportViewer is referenced trough this directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

And then instantiated in the page in this way:

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="_rptData" runat="server" Width="100%">
 </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Everything else is made codebehind (in c#):

```
 _rptData.Visible = true;
 _rptData.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(@"rptData.rdlc");
 _rptData.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;

 if (_rptData.LocalReport.DataSources.Count > 0)
      _rptData.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

 _rptData.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", _dt));

 _rptData.DataBind();
```

For some reason when I show the page the toolbar of the report is rendered in this way:

[image: ReportViewer toolbar corrupted]

In the same site just in different folder I have similar pages showing up reports with the 'correct' tollbar:

[image: ReportViewer toolbar]

Where's the problem?

Comment: Another issue probably related to this one is a fault in the Intellisense parsing that fails to identify the `ReportViewer` tag. When compiling anyway the object is correctly recognized and everything works (whether is it rendered correctly or not).

Comment: The last issue is fixed by adding the:

`Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"`